# Error :- Couldn't codesign Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: codesign

Tags: ios, swift

I am new in ios and could not recognise solution for error shown below

**Error** Couldn't codesign Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: codesign

[image: Error appearing is shown in image below]

what should i do to resolve this kind of error

Comment: did you resolve the issue?

Comment: @DanielGalasko Sometimes by cleaning and removing derived data this error gets removed and sometime doesn't.

Comment: I found that changing the provisioning profile worked for me. Ended up deleting everything from keychain and setting the profile to "iOS Developer" and not "iOS Developer(ABC123)"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I codesign a Swift app via the commandline?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25297638/how-do-i-codesign-a-swift-app-via-the-commandline)

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same issue when I was trying to build an app using developer profile. Even after setting proper code signing identity and provisioning profile, the same error appeared. Then I found that libswiftcore.dylib in test target was not code signed. So I had to set proper provisioning profile and code signing identity for my test target as well.

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer:

Open `Settings (Cmd + ,) -> Accounts` and add your developer profile there (I mean your login and password)

## Long answer

Once I faced this problem. I solved this way: after I installed Xcode on my new mac, created new developer certificate at developer.apple.com, created development provisioning profile for my app this error pop up. It turned out that I forgot to put my developer account to `Settings -> Accounts` tab.

Answer (score 0):

I set same provision profile for target as well then it start working.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me: updating Xcode to the latest version (from 7.2.x to 7.3.x). ^^;;